# Passing parameter to a class constructor in Dart

Tags: flutter, class, dart, constructor

I'm new to Flutter/Dart and having been going through some books and tutorials. I came across this class constructor.

```
class GroceryItemScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(GroceryItem) onCreate;
  final Function(GroceryItem) onUpdate;
  final GroceryItem? originalItem;
  final bool isUpdating;

  const GroceryItemScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.onCreate,
    required this.onUpdate,
    this.originalItem,
  })  : isUpdating = (originalItem != null),
        super(key: key)
...
}
```

What I don't understand and can't find an explanation for is this part.

`: isUpdating = (originalItem !=null)`

TIA

Comment: Look at https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors and scroll down a page or two to "initializer list"

Comment: Great. Thanks for link.

Answer (score 0):

This is as initializer. isUpdating will false or true depending on originalItem is null or not